# Prove that $\det(A^{T}A) \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

How to prove that $\det(A^{T}A) \neq 0$ if coloumns of $A$ are linearly independent, without using Cauchy-Binet formula? $A$ is real matrix.

Comment: How much do you know? Determinant of product is product of determinant? Linearly independent columns if determinant is nonzero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are assuming that $A$ is real and $n\times m$.

Suppose that $\det(A^TA)=0$. Then there exists nonzero $v\in \mathbb R^n$ such that $A^TAv=0$. Then 
$$
0=A^TAv=v^TA^TAv=(Av)^TAv.
$$
For any real vector $w$, if $w^Tw=0$, then $w=0$. Thus, $Av=0$. But this is exactly, if $C_1,\ldots,C_m$ are the columns of $A$,
$$
0=v_1C_1+v_2C_2+\cdots+v_mC_m.
$$
So the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent.

If follows that if the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, then $\det(A^TA)\ne0$.

Comment: Thank you! But what happens when matrix is over any field, not real?

Comment: I mean field has no zero divisors, and it's OK, isn't it?

Comment: @AnatoliySultanov In general fields, the result itself may not hold. For instance, in $\Bbb F_2$: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=(0)$$ and in $\Bbb C$ $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ i\end{pmatrix}=(0)$$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli In which fields result holds?

Comment: It holds in fields where the definition $ \langle v, w \rangle = v^T w $ defines an inner product, in particular, it has to satisfy the condition that $ \langle v, v \rangle = 0 $ iff $ v = 0 $. This cannot hold in fields of nonzero characteristic, such as $ \mathbb{F}_2 $, where the vector $ v = (1, 1) $ in $\mathbb{F}_2^2$ is an easy counterexample, as noted above; and it may even fail if the field is of characteristic zero, such as the case with $\mathbb{C} $.

Answer (score 3):

We can prove a much more general (and useful) result.

> **Theorem.** The (real) matrices $A$ and $A^TA$ have the same null space, hence the same rank.

(I'll use $N(B)$ to denote the null space of $B$: $N(B)=\{v:Bv=0\}$.)

*Proof*. It is obvious that $N(A)\subseteq N(A^TA)$. Suppose $v\in N(A^TA)$; then $A^TAv=0$ implies $v^TA^TAv=0$, so $(Av)^T(Av)=0$, hence $Av=0$.

If $A$ is $m\times n$, then the rank of $A$ is $n-\dim N(A)$ by the rank-nullity theorem. Similarly the rank of $A^TA$ is $n-\dim N(A^TA)$, thus proving the claim.$~\square$

In the case when the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, then the rank of $A$ equals the number of columns; therefore the rank of $A^TA$ equals the number of columns. Since $A^TA$ is square, it follows it is invertible, so $\det(A^TA)\ne0$.

---

Note that this exploits the fact that the matrices are real and the result need not hold over other fields. For a counterexample, consider the complex matrix
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1\\i\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then
$$
A^TA=\begin{bmatrix}1 & i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\i\end{bmatrix}=[0]
$$

The result holds in ordered fields, where a sum of nonzero squares is nonzero. More generally, over fields where $-1$ is not a sum of squares (because they can be ordered). A counterexample can always be found when $-1$ is a sum of squares: if $-1=a_1^2+\dots+a_n^2$, then the matrix
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\\vdots\\a_n\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
has $A^TA=0$.

Comment: +1, but: "where $-1$ is not a square" should be "where $-1$ is not a sum of squares"; otherwise you would be picking up the fields $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p$ prime congruent to $3$ modulo $4$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg That's what I meant to write, but the sum remained in my mind

Answer (score 1):

Since the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent then $A$ is injective. In fact if $Ae_1,\ldots,Ae_n$ are the columns of $A$ and if $x=\sum_{i=1}^nx_ie_i\in \ker A$ then $0=Ax=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i Ae_i\implies x_i=0\implies x=0$. Now if $\det(A^TA)=0$ then $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$ and let $x$ an associated eigenvector. Then
$$0=\langle A^TAx,x\rangle=\Vert Ax\Vert^2\implies Ax=0\iff x\in\ker A$$
which is an obvious contradiction.